# smoothing polarization covariance matrices

Tags: covariance, smoothing, healpy, polarization

There are implementations for smoothing spin 2 quantities like the Stokes Q and U: an example is healpy's [smoothing](http://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.sphtfunc.smoothing.html). Does a similar implementation exist for smoothing (via Gaussian convolution) a covariance matrix of polarization quantities? e.g. sigma_QU, sigma_IQ, and so forth.